# Can't point one position at another in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I may be misunderstanding the way positions work, but they're not working the way I would expect.  If I create two Object3Ds I would expect to be able to give the position property of the second a reference to the first so that it follows it, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
var foo = new THREE.Object3D();
foo.position = new THREE.Vector3(100, 200, 300);

var bar= new THREE.Object3D();
bar.position = foo.position;

console.log(foo.position); //{100, 200, 300}
console.log(bar.position); //{0, 0, 0}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  There is another way that seems to create a new Vector3:

```
var foo = new THREE.Object3D();
foo.position = new THREE.Vector3(100, 200, 300);

var bar= new THREE.Object3D();
bar.position = foo.position.copy();

console.log(foo.position); //{100, 200, 300}
console.log(bar.position); //{100, 200, 300}
```

As this creates a new Vector3, this works only until I move foo - then I have to update bar.position again.

(above is untested code!)

Answer (score 1):

```
bar.position.set(foo.position.x,foo.position.y,foo.position.z);
```

Always use class .set(x,y,z), don't use position = new.THREE.Vector3(1,2,3)

Comment: Thank you. But why?  Does set() do something more than just set the variable? Also, as foo.position.x is a Number and therefore a primitive, surely it will pass a value instead of a reference and I will be back to copying values across every frame?

Comment: More reasons, move object in existing scene is not only about changing coordinates at his attributes. There are lights, shadows ... etc to need to be recalculated. class .set() or translateZ() ... is solving all this work at once.

Comment: I see. So using the API of an object is always safer than accessing properties directly. I would expect position to be a private property - but then there's probably cases when you might want to set it directly if you know what the difference is. I'll use set() whenever I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one object to follow e.g. attach it to another  then you would need to `.add()`  the following object to the one being followed.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cdc1u9dk/  where you can click on the cube and the cube jumps a bit to the left and the sphere 'follows' the cube since it was attached to it in line 19 `cube.add( sphere );`

Comment: I've been avoiding that as I don't want my scenegraph to get too deep for performance reasons.  Otherwise, yes, this would be the right approach.

Comment: Only if you never let object moving individually towards scene again.